# grabbing all .nc files from URL to get data using matlab

Tags: matlab, url, netcdf

I d like to get all .nc files from URL to get and read the data using matlab. However, the filename is always very long and vary amongst all files. 
For instance, I have

```
    url = 'http://sourcename/filename.nc'
```

the sourcename is always the same, however the filename is very long and vary, so I would like to just use * to be able to grab whatever .nc file in the url

e.g.

```
    url = 'http://sourcename/*.nc'
```

but this does not work and I am guessing I need to get the exact name - so I am not sure what to do here?

On the other hand, it could be also interesting for me to get the name of each file and record it, but not sure how to do that either.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

HTTP does not implement a filesystem abstraction.  This means that each of those URLs that you request could be handled in a completely different way.  There is also in many cases no way to get a list of allowable URLs off of a parent (a directory listing, in other words).

It may be the case for you that `http://sourcename/` actually returns an index document containing a list of the files.  In that case, first fetch that document.  Then you'll have to parse the contents to extract the list of files.  Then you can loop over those files, form new URLs for each one, and fetch them in sequence.

Comment: mm Ok - thanks for your comments. Although can you please be bit more explicit in the second part; 'In that case, first fetch that document. Then you'll have to parse the contents to extract the list of files. Then you can loop over those files, form new URLs for each one, and fetch them in sequence.'

Comment: How would you implement this in matlab?

Comment: Let me rephrase.  Where do you get the list of files when you put them manually?  How do you know for each dataset what filename.nc is?  Once you describe that, we can probably help you automate.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of the file names in a text file, you can use the `wget` utility to process the file and fetch all the listed files.  This file would be formatted as follows:

```
http://url.com/file1.nc
http://url.com/file2.nc
(etc)
```

You would then invoke `wget` as follows:

```
$ wget -i url-file.txt
```

Alternatively, you may be able to use `wget` to fetch the files recursively, if they are all located in the same directory on the web server, e.g.:

```
$ wget -r -l1 http://url.com/directory
```

The `-r` flag says to recurse, the `-l1` flag says to go no deeper than 1 level when recursing.

This solution is external to Matlab, but once you have all of the files downloaded, you can work with them all locally.

`wget` is a fairly standard utility available on linux systems.  It is also available for OSX and Windows as well.  The `wget` homepage is here:  https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/